# Website partially loading background images (Bootstrap)

Tags: css, gallery, loading

I'm building a gallery and while all my code is working fine in Dreamweaver, when I upload the finished product to my website, only about half of the images are showing up.  I have checked the site on Chrome and Internet Explorer and had others check to see if it was just my PC.

The images are loaded as background images with this code:

```
.birdzoom {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}

#bird01 { 
    background-image: url(../images/thumbs/001.jpg); 
}
```

And displayed with this code:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 imgbox">
    <div class="thumb bird birdzoom" id="bird01">
    <div class="link" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)"></div>
        <div class="tags"><a href="purchase.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="birdname">Name</div>
</div>
```

The first 18 images show up fine and I've quadruple checked to make sure that all the images use the same code.

Site in question is http://birdbrained.waywardstudios.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Stylesheet

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

...

    #bird01 {
        background-image: url(../images/thumbs/001.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
    }

    #bird02 {
        background-image: url(../images/thumbs/002.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
    }

    ...

**you have not set the bird19 to bird58**
#bird19 {
        background-image: url(../images/thumbs/019.jpg);
   ...
```

**you have only set the image 1 to 18 **